# How is the bsearch() function in the standard C library implemented?

Tags: implementation, c99, bsearch

Does anyone know how the standard binary search function is implemented?

This is the prototype.

```
void * bsearch (const void*, const void*, size_t, size_t, int (*) (const void *, const void *) );
```

I'm really curious about how they used void pointers.

Comment: Beware of code attuned to GCC - that treats 'void *' as equivalent to 'char *' for computing addresses, whereas the C Standard says that you cannot do address arithmetic on 'void *' values.

Comment: @Jonathan: I'm not sure how GCC comes into this; the prototype he listed (the only place `void *` is mentioned in the question) is straight out of the C99 standard.

Comment: I believe Jonathan's comment was about some implementation of `bsearch` relying on arithmetic on `void *`.  A portable implementation (i.e., implementation that's standard-compliant itself) can't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are interested in knowing how `void *` pointers are used in `bsearch`, rather than the actual binary search algorithm itself.  The prototype for `bsearch` is:

```
void *bsearch(const void *key, const void *base,
    size_t nmemb, size_t size,
    int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

Here, `void *` is used so that any arbitrary type can be searched.  The interpretation of the pointers is done by the (user-supplied) `compar` function.

Since the pointer `base` points to the beginning of an array, and an array's elements are guaranteed to be contiguous, `bsearch` can get a `void *` pointer to any of the `nmemb` elements in the array by doing pointer arithmetic.  For example, to get a pointer to the fifth element in the array (assuming `nmemb >= 5`):

```
unsigned char *base_p = base;
size_t n = 5;
/* Go 5 elements after base */
unsigned char *curr = base_p + size*n;
/* curr now points to the 5th element of the array.
   Moreover, we can pass curr as the first or the second parameter
   to 'compar', because of implicit and legal conversion of curr to void *
   in the call */
```

In the above snippet, we couldn't add `size*n` directly to `base` because it is of type `void *`, and arithmetic on `void *` is not defined.

Comment: @Dave: What part are you referring to?

Comment: The casting from (void *) to (char *). 
Anyways I've checked and it's allowed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

See [bsearch @ Google's codesearch](http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=bsearch&hl=en&btnG=Search+Code) 
for different implementations of `bsearch`.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the source. If you have VS Standard or better, see:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\crt\src\bsearch.c